# Do whitespaces is normal in css?

Tags: css

I like to code this way:

```
h1    {color:red;}
```

but in w3shools they make it like that:

```
h1    {color: red;}
```

Is it the same end-results?

Comment: Yes it is. It's just individual preference. A space between the property and the value wouldn't make red into another color.

Answer (score 0):

Yes both will give you the same result. We follow the whitespaces just to give good look and indentation to our css so that the code will be easily readable to other developers also. If you see any minified css (with .min.css extension) you can see there are no white spaces in it.